# Export Dataset<Row> to CSV

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, export-to-csv

I'm trying to generate a CSV file based on some Spark SQL results.

I tried to fill all null values but in vain. Seems like something linked to the way I'm configuring it.

Here is the code I'm running.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Workshop").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
SQLContext sqlContext= new SQLContext(spark);

Dataset<Row> customers = spark.read().option("header", "true").csv(pathToCustomers);
Dataset<Row> unsubscribed = spark.read().option("header", "true").csv(pathToUnsubscribed);
Dataset<Row> cleaned = spark.read().option("header", "true").csv(pathToCleaned);

sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(customers, "customers");
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(unsubscribed, "unsubscribed");        
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(cleaned, "cleaned");        

//Run the query then the split
Dataset<Row> deleteUnsubscribed = sqlContext.sql("select * from customers where Email not in (select Email_Address from unsubscribed)");   

sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(deleteUnsubscribed, "deleteUnsubscribed");        

Dataset<Row> deleteCleaned = sqlContext.sql("select * from deleteUnsubscribed where Email not in (select Email_Address from cleaned)"); 
deleteCleaned.write().option("sep", ";").option("header", "true").csv("Data/customers.csv");
```

This generates the folowing error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:147)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:492)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:198)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:579)
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.deleteCleanedAndUnsubscribedFromCustomers(DemoApplication.java:114)
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:124)

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 8, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:404)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:678)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:661)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:639)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:468)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:424)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:905)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:886)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:783)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CSVRelation.scala:208)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVOutputWriterFactory.newInstance(CSVRelation.scala:178)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.<init>(FileFormatWriter.scala:234)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:182)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:129)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:127)
... 22 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:404)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:678)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:661)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:639)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:468)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:424)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:905)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:886)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:783)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CSVRelation.scala:208)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVOutputWriterFactory.newInstance(CSVRelation.scala:178)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.<init>(FileFormatWriter.scala:234)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:182)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:129)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source0)
```

I tried with a smaller dataset (this dataset contains 57548 row) but same error.

And here is the pom file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                 <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
                 <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
               <exclusion>
                 <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
                 <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
             </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
       <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I'm still new to the Spark processing so it could be just a nooby error from a misunderstanding.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is nothing obviously wrong with this particular snippet. Could you try to reduce it to a [mcve] and possibly add relevant context? Also a note - 2.1 is a pretty old version (2.4 has been already released) and outdated even on 2.1 branch.

Comment: Well thanks alot for the comment, seems like i wasn't putting the Hadop winutils.exe file on the rights place.

Comment: I am glad you resolved it. For the future reference - if use MS Windows for development it is good to mentioned that in the question. Spark and Windows don't play along that well. Also, please don't forget to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well thanks to @user6910411, what i've done is updating the version to 2.4.0 and it given me clear error log IOException (null) string in command
So i just copy pasted the winutils.exe file to the Haddop root folder and made sure the environment variable is pointing at the root folder and not other branch.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the CSV file and after some manipulation.  We can use this to write to CSV

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").schema(schema).csv("C:\\In\\input.csv");
df.write().format("csv").save("C:\\Out\\output.csv");
```